# passing an object to a function with mustache.js

Tags: mustache, template-engine

Is there a way to pass an object to a function with mustache.js templates?

Something like :

```
var template = $('#template').html();
var json = {folder : 'abc', size : '123', date : '1'};
var output = Mustache.render(template, json);


<script type="template/text" id="template">
    <td><span class="{{folder}}" onclick="doSomething(json)"></span>
</script>
```

I didn't find any way to do that, so I guess it's not possible, and if so, which templating engine can do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this...

*** handlebars helper ***

```
json: function(obj) {
  return JSON.stringify(obj)
}
```

**server**

```
var crypto = {}
res.locals = {
  crypto: crypto
}
```

***client***

```
<script>
    var crypto = {{{json crypto}}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the event handlers after the html has been rendered. Some thing like:

```
<script type="template/text" id="template">
    <td><span class="{{folder}} folder" onclick="doSomething(json)"></span>
</script>

var template = $('#template').html();
var json = {folder : 'abc', size : '123', date : '1'};
var output = Mustache.render(template, json);

$(".folder").on('click', function(){
  //make use of json object here
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="template/text" id="template">
    <td><span onclick="myFunction({{json}})">{{variable}}</span></td>
</script>


var data={
    variable:'some stuff',
    json: function() {
       return JSON.stringify(data)
    }
};


var template = $('#template').html();

var output = Mustache.render(template, data);

var myFunction=function(data){
    console.log(data);
};
```